# Добавить строчку в базу данных исходя из условия

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Здравствуйте. У меня есть одна база данных с одной таблицей. 
Мне нужно, чтобы с разных страниц в эту базу добавлялись данные из php формы.
Буквально это выглядит так: 
На первой странице человек добавляет название и описание. На другой странице, другой человек, зная название, может добавить приписку. Но я не могу сделать так, чтобы это происходило исходя из условия. "Если имя совпадает, значит добавить в строчку базы данных к ЭТОМУ имени".

1.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "s24536_yana", "*****") or die("Нет соединения");
mysql_select_db("s24536_yana", $db);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO news(`name`,`text`) VALUES('$name','$text') ");
echo 'Спасибо, ваша работа добавлена';
?>
```

2.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mark = $_POST['mark'];
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "s24536_yana", "*****") or die("Нет соединения");
mysql_select_db("s24536_yana", $db);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO news(`mark`) VALUES('$mark') ");
echo 'Спасибо за оценку';
?>
```

Вот два куска кода. Второй кусок должен добавлять mark туда, где совпадает name (name мы получаем из формы).
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Огромное спасибо человеку, который написал мне почти полное решение, но почему-то исчез. 
Немного доработал, получилось так:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mark = $_POST['mark'];
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "s24536_yana", "*****") or die("Нет соединения");
mysql_select_db("s24536_yana", $db);
$row = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM news WHERE name = '$name'"); // Если значение будет 1, тогда совпадение найдено, 0 значит 
 // не найдено.

$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($row);

if($fetch['count'] != 0) { // Совпадение найдено, добавляем.
mysql_query("UPDATE news SET mark='$mark' WHERE name='$name'");
} else {
echo "Извините, но такой записи нет.";
}
?>
```

То есть совпадение проверяем через PHP, а потом обновляем базу через UPDATE, используя при этом WHERE, чтобы определить нужную строку по name.

Comment: Расширение mysql в php считается устаревшим. Старайтесь в новых проектах использовать PDO.